# NodeJS URL Routing and Render HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im new at nodejs programming and im having a little problem now. When i try to go localhost:3000/ i want to go homeController and index function prints the HTML file.

## APP.JS

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

const app = express();

const homeController = require('./home/homeController.js');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(homeController.index);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 80!'))
```

## HOMECONTROLLER.JS

```
var path    = require("path");

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
};

console.log('test33');
```

Also i am using exports to seperate app.js from other controllers. Is this the right way? I have a history with Python Django framework and we used to use URLs to navigate our program.

Thanks.

## OUTPUT

> Cannot GET
>   /function%20(req,%20res)%7B%0A%20%20res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));%0A%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `homeController.index` is a function, but you're not calling it. Replace:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(homeController.index);
});
```

with:

```
app.get('/', homeController.index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `homeController.js` exports an `index` function which requires two parameters `req`and `res`.
So you have to update your app.js accordingly :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  homeController.index(req, res);
});
```

edit: by the way, your app is listening to port **3000**